# Why pure javascript cannot get the public IP of a client?

Tags: javascript, browser

Why pure javascript running as client side code on browser cannot get the public IP of a client?

I know that public IP address can retrieved by making a call to a server. But I am more interested in the reason as to why pure js can do the job.

I reviewed this question: [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript). The answers rather provides solution but doesn't gives information on whey it is not possible.

Comment: "Pure javascript" can't do anything, it doesn't have any IO. I suppose you refer to the various APIs that are exposed to JS running in a browser?

Comment: @Bergi That is what I meant, I have updated my question better reflect that. Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Answer (score 2):

1. Privacy. Direct access to the host machine's resources is only accessible with user permission, but this isn't the only reason.
2. Routing with NAT: the **public** address is often set on the outside interface of a router. Mostly there's no way to get that information without logging in to the router (but see 1. above), or asking some other external machine to tell you.